# PHP Mktime error

Tags: php, mktime

I'm all of a sudden getting the following error on a site that I've done, which has been working fine so far:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mktime() [function.mktime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Antarctica/Macquarie' for 'EST/10.0/no DST' instead
```

This is the code in question:

```
$stamp=mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);
```

What's the issue here? How can I quickly make these errors go away? I'm using `mktime` in that format in a lot of places and its throwing an error in each place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error says, you either need to specify a timezone using `date_default_timezone_set('Antarctica/Macquarie');` or `ini_set('date.timezone', 'Antarctica/Macquarie');` in your code or define `date.timezone` in `php.ini`.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that i'd need to use in the php.ini file?

Comment: I don't recommend this, especially if this is going to be in a production environment. But if this is just something you are doing for fun or something you could just suppress the warning like: 

`$stamp = @mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year);`

It's not a good thing to get in a habit of though.So you should probably just fix you php.ini

Comment: @PaulPRO - Timestamps are an important concept when dealing with dates, especially since timestamp are based on the Unix Epoch (which is GMT). One should **never** suppress the error messages unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Click Upvote - Make sure to restart your web server if you change `php.ini` as the changes will only take effect when it's restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that `$month`, `$day`, and `$year` are INT - or even not NULL?

Also look into [date_default_timezone_set()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)